# Error for rosmake mav_tools

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I have successfully installed mav_tools. However, when I run 'rosmake mav_tools' below error occurs:

viki@ROS:~$ rosmake mav_tools
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['mav_tools']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/viki/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130819-202848
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['mav_tools'] to:
['mav_odom_interface', 'mav_ctrl_interface', 'quad_joy_teleop', 'ab_filter', 'laser_height_estimation', 'mav_msgs', 'flyer_interface', 'mav_simple_ctrl_interface', 'mav_srvs', 'city_flyer_rgbd_launch', 'city_flyer_launch', 'mav_common']
cannot find required resource: navigation
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/viki/ros_workspace
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

My ubuntu version is: VirtualBox virtual image with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS and ROS Fuerte .

Please give me your help. Thx.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73834/error-for-rosmake-mav_tools/) by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2013-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that it can not find the navigation stack, have you installed it correct and do you find it ? Try `roscd navigation` , does it work?

If not you migth have not installed the navigation stack, you can install it by typing `sudo apt-get install ros-<ROS_REALESE>-navigation`, if you use fuerte you would type `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-navigation`

Hope that help you

---

Originally posted by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) with karma: 336 on 2013-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2013-08-20**:
Hi ooon, thx for your help. It not works and show "no such package/stack 'navigation'". Would you please instruct me how to install navigation package?

**Comment by [Sendoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/6040/sendoh/) on 2013-08-21**:
Thanks so much, ooon. I can make mav_tool successfully so far.